# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/facebook/widget/LoginButton - Android Gradle Build Tools 1.2.3

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I am facing some weird issues regarding the Facebook SDK.

Currently we're using 1.1.3 of the Android Gradle Tools plugin `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'`

However if I want to upgrade to 1.2.3 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` I get this exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/facebook/widget/LoginButton
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Did anyone else run into the same problem?

We're using this version of the Facebook SDK:

`'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'`

Comment: Have you cleaned your build since making the Gradle change?

Comment: Yup I've tried that too